# Nil out a presentedViewController when UIApplication becomes active again

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a `presentedViewController` on top of the root view controller when the app gets dismissed. (e.g. User navigates to another app or goes back to the home screen.)

I would like to nil it out when the user reactivates the app without it being visible to them. Calling `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:` is not an option because it only works if the view controller is visible, and I'd like to do it sooner and specifically only in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and otherwise let the user continue their workflow in the modal view.

Are there any tricks I can use?

Comment: Call `dismiss...` with no animation when the app is about to go into the background.

Comment: Actually I'm a little unclear what you're up to. Why would you present something when the user leaves and then dismiss it before they come back? They will never get to interact with it so what's the point of it? Are you just trying to prevent something from appearing in the snapshot image? If so, that's not how to do it.

Comment: Calling `dismiss...` before the user leaves is not an option for me. In my specific case I need to dismiss the modal view if the user comes in via `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: ` or let the user continue their workflow in the modal view if they just relaunched the app from their home screen directly.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarifying that. You might want to edit your original question to be clearer about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, the only actual issue is what happens when the app receives `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and is thus brought to the front.

In that case, simply adjust your interface in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` - that is part of its purpose, to allow you to do that. You will be given some time before the "snapshot" is torn away, so if the adjustment involved is to dismiss an existing modal view, dismiss it without animation and there you are.

The user will still see the modal view for a moment, but not really - what the user is seeing is not *your* interface but the "snapshot" that was created by the system when the app when into the background. The "snapshot" is removed to reveal the actual interface (with a nice crossfade effect in iOS 7).

If the "snapshot" itself is problematic there are ways of preventing it from being taken, but it doesn't sound to me like this is that kind of situation.

(By the way, this raises the question of how the presented view is to know that it must be dismissed. The initial main action is in your app delegate, which is probably some conceptual distance away from the presented view. This would be an appropriate situation in which to use an NSNotification to communicate across this distance.)

Comment: Do you know of a callback or delegate I can override? When I try it in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, I get an `attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear.` warning in the console.

Comment: Then it must have been dismissed already. That sounds like another problem. Or else perhaps your app was terminated in the background, and so we are launching from scratch; you need to check for that, obviously.

Comment: And of course this is another reason to use the NSNotification! If the presented view controller is registered to receive the notification and to dismiss itself when the notification arrives, then it does no harm to post it, as either the presented view controller is there and will dismiss itself in response, or the presented view controller is not there and nothing will happen!